# Handeling events in nested fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

Here is my problem, I am opening a new fragament from first fragment's Gridview item click. In my 1st fragment to refresh the items of grid view. I have implemented swipetoRefresh functionality.
But when I am opening the 2nd fragment to show my grid items in horizontal scrollview. Here also if I do swipe to refresh(swaping my finger from top to bottom). Then my first fragment event occurs. I dont want my first fragment event on 2nd fragment. Please let me know how can I resolve it.

Below is my code to open new Fragment.

```
     Fragment newFragment = new SwipeFragment(featureArr, dataList, HomeFragment.this);

       // Log.e("position clicked is","-----"+position);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("pos", position);
        newFragment.setArguments(b);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = ((AppCompatActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transaction.add(R.id.frame_edit, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
// Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
```

Comment: use replace instead of add for fragment transaction

Comment: Hey @MilanPansuriya I just change from add to replace but same is happening my swipe to refresh is still active on 2nd fragment.